# Multiday Calendar Datepicker JQuery Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm using jQuery plugin from these websites [web](http://www.overset.com/2008/05/12/multiday-calendar-datepicker-jquery-plugin/) , [github](https://github.com/overset/jquery-jcal).

This is screenshot whith my problem:
[image]

For some reason some months are not full ie. last day in month transfer in next month. Why?

This is JavaScript:

```
(function($) {
$.fn.jCal = function(opt) {
    $.jCal(this, opt);
};
$.jCal = function(target, opt) {
    opt = $.extend({
        day : new Date(),
        days : 1,
        showMonths : 1,
        monthSelect : false,
        dCheck : function(day) {
            return true;
        },
        callback : function(day, days) {
            return true;
        },
        selectedBG : 'rgb(0, 143, 214)',
        defaultBG : 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
        dayOffset : 0,
        forceWeek : false,
        dow : [ 'S', 'M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S' ],
        ml : [ 'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December' ],
        ms : [ 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec' ],
        _target : target
    }, opt);
    opt.day = new Date(opt.day.getFullYear(), opt.day.getMonth(), 1);
    if (!$(opt._target).data('days')) $(opt._target).data('days', opt.days);
    $(target).stop().empty();
    for (var sm = 0; sm < opt.showMonths; sm++) $(target).append('<div class="jCalMo"></div>');
    opt.cID = 'c' + $('.jCalMo').length;$('.jCalMo', target).each(function(ind) {
        drawCalControl($(this), $.extend({}, opt, {
            'ind' : ind,
            'day' : new Date(new Date(opt.day.getTime()).setMonth(new Date(opt.day.getTime()).getMonth() + ind))
        }));drawCal($(this), $.extend({}, opt, {
            'ind' : ind,
            'day' : new Date(new Date(opt.day.getTime()).setMonth(new Date(opt.day.getTime()).getMonth() + ind))
        }));
    });
    if ($(opt._target).data('day') && $(opt._target).data('days')) reSelectDates(target, $(opt._target).data('day'), $(opt._target).data('days'), opt);
};
function drawCalControl(target, opt) {
    $(target).append('<div class="jCal">' + ((opt.ind == 0) ? '<div class="left" />' : '') + '<div class="month">' + '<span class="monthYear">' + opt.day.getFullYear() + '</span>' + '<span class="monthName">' + opt.ml[opt.day.getMonth()] + '</span>' + '</div>' + ((opt.ind == (opt.showMonths - 1)) ? '<div class="right" />' : '') + '</div>');
    if (opt.monthSelect) $(target).find('.jCal .monthName, .jCal .monthYear').bind('mouseover', $.extend({}, opt), function(e) {
            $(this).removeClass('monthYearHover').removeClass('monthNameHover');
            if ($('.jCalMask', e.data._target).length == 0) $(this).addClass($(this).attr('class') + 'Hover');
        }).bind('mouseout', function() {
            $(this).removeClass('monthYearHover').removeClass('monthNameHover');
        }).bind('click', $.extend({}, opt), function(e) {
            $('.jCalMo .monthSelector, .jCalMo .monthSelectorShadow').remove();
            var monthName = $(this).hasClass('monthName'),
                pad = Math.max(parseInt($(this).css('padding-left')), parseInt($(this).css('padding-left'))) || 2,
                calcTop = (($(this).offset()).top - ((monthName ? e.data.day.getMonth() : 2) * ($(this).height() + 0)));
            calcTop = calcTop > 0 ? calcTop : 0;
            var topDiff = ($(this).offset()).top - calcTop;
            $('<div class="monthSelectorShadow" style="' + 'top:' + $(e.data._target).offset().top + 'px; ' + 'left:' + $(e.data._target).offset().left + 'px; ' + 'width:' + ($(e.data._target).width() + (parseInt($(e.data._target).css('paddingLeft')) || 0) + (parseInt($(e.data._target).css('paddingRight')) || 0)) + 'px; ' + 'height:' + ($(e.data._target).height() + (parseInt($(e.data._target).css('paddingTop')) || 0) + (parseInt($(e.data._target).css('paddingBottom')) || 0)) + 'px;">' + '</div>').css('opacity', 0.01).appendTo($(this).parent());$('<div class="monthSelector" style="' + 'top:' + calcTop + 'px; ' + 'left:' + (($(this).offset()).left) + 'px; ' + 'width:' + ($(this).width() + (pad * 2)) + 'px;">' + '</div>').css('opacity', 0).appendTo($(this).parent());
            for (var di = (monthName ? 0 : -2), dd = (monthName ? 12 : 3); di < dd; di++) $(this).clone().removeClass('monthYearHover').removeClass('monthNameHover').addClass('monthSelect').attr('id', monthName ? (di + 1) + '_1_' + e.data.day.getFullYear() : (e.data.day.getMonth() + 1) + '_1_' + (e.data.day.getFullYear() + di)).html(monthName ? e.data.ml[di] : (e.data.day.getFullYear() + di)).css('top', ($(this).height() * di)).appendTo($(this).parent().find('.monthSelector'));
            var moSel = $(this).parent().find('.monthSelector').get(0),
                diffOff = $(moSel).height() - ($(moSel).height() - topDiff);
            $(moSel).css('clip', 'rect(' + diffOff + 'px ' + ($(this).width() + (pad * 2)) + 'px ' + diffOff + 'px 0px)').animate({
                'opacity' : .92,
                'clip' : 'rect(0px ' + ($(this).width() + (pad * 2)) + 'px ' + $(moSel).height() + 'px 0px)'
            }, 'fast', function() {
                $(this).parent().find('.monthSelectorShadow').bind('mouseover click', function() {
                    $(this).parent().find('.monthSelector').remove();$(this).remove();
                });
            }).parent().find('.monthSelectorShadow').animate({
                'opacity' : .1
            }, 'fast');$('.jCalMo .monthSelect', e.data._target).bind('mouseover mouseout click', $.extend({}, e.data), function(e) {
                if (e.type == 'click') $(e.data._target).jCal($.extend(e.data, {
                        day : new Date($(this).attr('id').replace(/_/g, '/'))
                    }));else
                    $(this).toggleClass('monthSelectHover');
            });
        });
    $(target).find('.jCal .left').bind('click', $.extend({}, opt), function(e) {
        if ($('.jCalMask', e.data._target).length > 0) return false;
        var mD = {
            w : 0,
            h : 0
        };
        $('.jCalMo', e.data._target).each(function() {
            mD.w += $(this).width() + parseInt($(this).css('padding-left')) + parseInt($(this).css('padding-right'));
            var cH = $(this).height() + parseInt($(this).css('padding-top')) + parseInt($(this).css('padding-bottom'));
            mD.h = ((cH > mD.h) ? cH : mD.h);
        });$(e.data._target).prepend('<div class="jCalMo"></div>');
        e.data.day = new Date($('div[id*=' + e.data.cID + 'd_]:first', e.data._target).attr('id').replace(e.data.cID + 'd_', '').replace(/_/g, '/'));e.data.day.setDate(1);e.data.day.setMonth(e.data.day.getMonth() - 1);drawCalControl($('.jCalMo:first', e.data._target), e.data);drawCal($('.jCalMo:first', e.data._target), e.data);
        if (e.data.showMonths > 1) {
            $('.right', e.data._target).clone(true).appendTo($('.jCalMo:eq(' + (e.data.showMonths - 1) + ') .jCal', e.data._target));$('.left:last, .right:last', e.data._target).remove();
        }
        $(e.data._target).append('<div class="jCalSpace" style="width:' + mD.w + 'px; height:' + mD.h + 'px;"></div>');$('.jCalMo', e.data._target).wrapAll('<div class="jCalMask" style="clip:rect(0px ' + mD.w + 'px ' + mD.h + 'px 0px); width:' + (mD.w + (mD.w / e.data.showMonths)) + 'px; height:' + mD.h + 'px;">' + '<div class="jCalMove"></div>' + '</div>');$('.jCalMove', e.data._target).css('margin-left', ((mD.w / e.data.showMonths) * -1) + 'px').css('opacity', 0.5).animate({
            marginLeft : '0px'
        }, 'fast', function() {
            $(this).children('.jCalMo:not(:last)').appendTo($(e.data._target));$('.jCalSpace, .jCalMask', e.data._target).empty().remove();
            if ($(e.data._target).data('day')) reSelectDates(e.data._target, $(e.data._target).data('day'), $(e.data._target).data('days'), e.data);
        });
    });$(target).find('.jCal .right').bind('click', $.extend({}, opt), function(e) {
        if ($('.jCalMask', e.data._target).length > 0) return false;
        var mD = {
            w : 0,
            h : 0
        };
        $('.jCalMo', e.data._target).each(function() {
            mD.w += $(this).width() + parseInt($(this).css('padding-left')) + parseInt($(this).css('padding-right'));
            var cH = $(this).height() + parseInt($(this).css('padding-top')) + parseInt($(this).css('padding-bottom'));
            mD.h = ((cH > mD.h) ? cH : mD.h);
        });$(e.data._target).append('<div class="jCalMo"></div>');
        e.data.day = new Date($('div[id^=' + e.data.cID + 'd_]:last', e.data._target).attr('id').replace(e.data.cID + 'd_', '').replace(/_/g, '/'));e.data.day.setDate(1);e.data.day.setMonth(e.data.day.getMonth() + 1);drawCalControl($('.jCalMo:last', e.data._target), e.data);drawCal($('.jCalMo:last', e.data._target), e.data);
        if (e.data.showMonths > 1) {
            $('.left', e.data._target).clone(true).prependTo($('.jCalMo:eq(1) .jCal', e.data._target));$('.left:first, .right:first', e.data._target).remove();
        }
        $(e.data._target).append('<div class="jCalSpace" style="width:' + mD.w + 'px; height:' + mD.h + 'px;"></div>');$('.jCalMo', e.data._target).wrapAll('<div class="jCalMask" style="clip:rect(0px ' + mD.w + 'px ' + mD.h + 'px 0px); width:' + (mD.w + (mD.w / e.data.showMonths)) + 'px; height:' + mD.h + 'px;">' + '<div class="jCalMove"></div>' + '</div>');$('.jCalMove', e.data._target).css('opacity', 0.5).animate({
            marginLeft : ((mD.w / e.data.showMonths) * -1) + 'px'
        }, 'fast', function() {
            $(this).children('.jCalMo:not(:first)').appendTo($(e.data._target));$('.jCalSpace, .jCalMask', e.data._target).empty().remove();
            if ($(e.data._target).data('day')) reSelectDates(e.data._target, $(e.data._target).data('day'), $(e.data._target).data('days'), e.data);
            $(this).children('.jCalMo:not(:first)').removeClass('');
        });
    });$('.jCal', target).each(function() {
        var width = $(this).parent().width() - ($('.left', this).width() || 0) - ($('.right', this).width() || 0);
        $('.month', this).css('width', width).find('.monthName, .monthYear').css('width', ((width / 2) - 4));
    });$(window).load(function() {
        $('.jCal', target).each(function() {
            var width = $(this).parent().width() - ($('.left', this).width() || 0) - ($('.right', this).width() || 0);
            $('.month', this).css('width', width).find('.monthName, .monthYear').css('width', ((width / 2) - 4));
        });
    });
}
;
function reSelectDates(target, day, days, opt) {
    var fDay = new Date(day.getTime());
    var sDay = new Date(day.getTime());
    for (var fC = false, di = 0, dC = days; di < dC; di++) {
        var dF = $(target).find('div[id*=d_' + (sDay.getMonth() + 1) + '_' + sDay.getDate() + '_' + sDay.getFullYear() + ']');
        if (dF.length > 0) {
            dF.stop().addClass('selectedDay');
            fC = true;
        }
        sDay.setDate(sDay.getDate() + 1);
    }
    if (fC && typeof opt.callback == 'function') opt.callback(day, days);
}
;
function drawCal(target, opt) {
    for (var ds = 0, length = opt.dow.length; ds < length; ds++) {
        $(target).append('<div class="dow">' + opt.dow[ds] + '</div>');
    }

    var fd = new Date(new Date(opt.day.getTime()).setDate(1));
    var ldlm = new Date(new Date(fd.getTime()).setDate(0));
    var ld = new Date(new Date(new Date(fd.getTime()).setMonth(fd.getMonth() + 1)).setDate(0));
    var copt = {
        fd : fd.getDay(),
        lld : ldlm.getDate(),
        ld : ld.getDate()
    };
    var offsetDayStart = ((copt.fd < opt.dayOffset) ? (opt.dayOffset - 7) : 1);
    var offsetDayEnd = ((ld.getDay() < opt.dayOffset) ? (7 - ld.getDay()) : ld.getDay());
    for (var d = offsetDayStart, dE = (copt.fd + copt.ld + (7 - offsetDayEnd)); d < dE; d++) $(target).append(((d <= (copt.fd - opt.dayOffset)) ? '<div id="' + opt.cID + 'd' + d + '" class="pday">' + (copt.lld - ((copt.fd - opt.dayOffset) - d)) + '</div>' : ((d > ((copt.fd - opt.dayOffset) + copt.ld)) ? '<div id="' + opt.cID + 'd' + d + '" class="aday">' + (d - ((copt.fd - opt.dayOffset) + copt.ld)) + '</div>' : '<div id="' + opt.cID + 'd_' + (fd.getMonth() + 1) + '_' + (d - (copt.fd - opt.dayOffset)) + '_' + fd.getFullYear() + '" class="' + ((opt.dCheck(new Date((new Date(fd.getTime())).setDate(d - (copt.fd - opt.dayOffset))))) ? 'day' : 'invday') + '">' + (d - (copt.fd - opt.dayOffset)) + '</div>')));
    $(target).find('div[id^=' + opt.cID + 'd]:first, div[id^=' + opt.cID + 'd]:nth-child(7n+2)').before('<br style="clear:both; font-size:0.1em;" />');$(target).find('div[id^=' + opt.cID + 'd_]:not(.invday)').bind("mouseover mouseout click", $.extend({}, opt), function(e) {
        if ($('.jCalMask', e.data._target).length > 0) return false;
        var osDate = new Date($(this).attr('id').replace(/c[0-9]{1,}d_([0-9]{1,2})_([0-9]{1,2})_([0-9]{4})/, '$1/$2/$3'));
        if (e.data.forceWeek) osDate.setDate(osDate.getDate() + (e.data.dayOffset - osDate.getDay()));
        var sDate = new Date(osDate.getTime());
        if (e.type == 'click') $('div[id*=d_]', e.data._target).stop().removeClass('selectedDay').removeClass('overDay').css('backgroundColor', '');
        for (var di = 0, ds = $(e.data._target).data('days'); di < ds; di++) {
            var currDay = $(e.data._target).find('#' + e.data.cID + 'd_' + (sDate.getMonth() + 1) + '_' + sDate.getDate() + '_' + sDate.getFullYear());
            if (currDay.length == 0 || $(currDay).hasClass('invday')) break;
            if (e.type == 'mouseover') $(currDay).addClass('overDay');
            else if (e.type == 'mouseout') $(currDay).stop().removeClass('overDay').css('backgroundColor', '');
            else if (e.type == 'click') $(currDay).stop().addClass('selectedDay');
            sDate.setDate(sDate.getDate() + 1);
        }
        if (e.type == 'click') {
            e.data.day = osDate;e.data.callback(osDate, di);
            di = ds;$(e.data._target).data('day', e.data.day).data('days', di);
        }
    });
};})(jQuery);
```

And code in html:

```
        <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="${contextPath}include/js/jCal.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript"> 
    var calSettings = {
        1:{calDay: 0, names: ['S','M','T','W','T','F','S']}, //sunday
        2:{calDay: 1, names: ['M','T','W','T','F','S','S']}, //monday
        3:{calDay: -5, names: ['T','W','T','F','S','S','M']}, //tuesday
        4:{calDay: -4, names: ['W','T','F','S','S','M','T']}, //wednesday
        5:{calDay: -3, names: ['T','F','S','S','M','T','W']}, //thursday
        6:{calDay: -2, names: ['F','S','S','M','T','W','T']}, //friday
        7:{calDay: -1, names: ['S','S','M','T','W','T','F']}}; //saturday

    busyDays= new Array($busyDays);
    calendarMaxDateTime = $calendarMaxDate.getTime();
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
                $('#calOne').jCal({
                    day:            new Date($calendarSetDate.getTime()),
                    days:           7,
                    showMonths:     5,
                    monthSelect:    true,
                    forceWeek:      true,   // force full week selection
                    dow:            calSettings[${defaultCheckinDay}].names,
                    callback:       function (day, days) {
                        if(days==7){//disabling selection of periods shorter than 7 days
                            document.getElementById('bookingForm1')["filter_date"].value=day.getDate();
                            document.getElementById('bookingForm1')["filter_month"].value=day.getMonth();
                            document.getElementById('bookingForm1')["filter_year"].value=day.getFullYear();
                            document.getElementById('bookingForm1').submit();
                            return true;
                        }
                        }
                    });
            });
    </script>
```

I dont know where is problem, i looking in this script few hours i cant detect bug. Plz help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changes two line of code in this function in JavaScript and now works:

```
function drawCal(target, opt) {
    for (var ds = 0, length = opt.dow.length; ds < length; ds++) $(target).append('<div class="dow">' + opt.dow[ds] + '</div>');
    var fd = new Date(new Date(opt.day.getTime()).setDate(1));
    var ldlm = new Date(new Date(fd.getTime()).setDate(0));
    var ld = new Date(new Date(new Date(fd.getTime()).setMonth(fd.getMonth() + 1)).setDate(0));
    var copt = {
        fd : fd.getDay(),
        lld : ldlm.getDate(),
        ld : ld.getDate()
    };
    var offsetDayStart = ((copt.fd < opt.dayOffset) ? (opt.dayOffset - 7) : 1);
    var offsetDayEnd = ((ld.getDay() < opt.dayOffset) ? (7 - ld.getDay()) : ld.getDay());
    if(offsetDayEnd == 6) offsetDayEnd = 5;
    for (var d = offsetDayStart, dE = (copt.fd + copt.ld + (7 - offsetDayEnd)); d < dE; d++) $(target).append(((d <= (copt.fd - opt.dayOffset)) ? '<div id="' + opt.cID + 'd' + d + '" class="pday">' + (copt.lld - ((copt.fd - opt.dayOffset) - d)) + '</div>' : ((d > ((copt.fd - opt.dayOffset) + copt.ld)) ? '<div id="' + opt.cID + 'd' + d + '" class="aday">' + (d - ((copt.fd - opt.dayOffset) + copt.ld)) + '</div>' : '<div id="' + opt.cID + 'd_' + (fd.getMonth() + 1) + '_' + (d - (copt.fd - opt.dayOffset)) + '_' + fd.getFullYear() + '" class="' + ((opt.dCheck(new Date((new Date(fd.getTime())).setDate(d - (copt.fd - opt.dayOffset))))) ? 'day' : 'invday') + '">' + (d - (copt.fd - opt.dayOffset)) + '</div>')));
    $(target).find('div[id^=' + opt.cID + 'd]:first, div[id^=' + opt.cID + 'd]:nth-child(7n+2)').before('<br style="clear:both; font-size:0.1em;" />');$(target).find('div[id^=' + opt.cID + 'd_]:not(.invday)').bind("mouseover mouseout click", $.extend({}, opt), function(e) {
        if ($('.jCalMask', e.data._target).length > 0) return false;
        var osDate = new Date($(this).attr('id').replace(/c[0-9]{1,}d_([0-9]{1,2})_([0-9]{1,2})_([0-9]{4})/, '$1/$2/$3'));
        osDate.setDate(osDate.getDate() + 1);
        if (e.data.forceWeek) osDate.setDate(osDate.getDate() + (e.data.dayOffset - osDate.getDay()));
        var sDate = new Date(osDate.getTime());
        if (e.type == 'click') $('div[id*=d_]', e.data._target).stop().removeClass('selectedDay').removeClass('overDay').css('backgroundColor', '');
        for (var di = 0, ds = $(e.data._target).data('days'); di < ds; di++) {
            var currDay = $(e.data._target).find('#' + e.data.cID + 'd_' + (sDate.getMonth() + 1) + '_' + sDate.getDate() + '_' + sDate.getFullYear());
            if (currDay.length == 0 || $(currDay).hasClass('invday')) break;
            if (e.type == 'mouseover') $(currDay).addClass('overDay');
            else if (e.type == 'mouseout') $(currDay).stop().removeClass('overDay').css('backgroundColor', '');
            else if (e.type == 'click') $(currDay).stop().addClass('selectedDay');
            sDate.setDate(sDate.getDate() + 1);
        }
        if (e.type == 'click') {
            e.data.day = osDate;e.data.callback(osDate, di);
            di = ds;$(e.data._target).data('day', e.data.day).data('days', di);
        }
    });
}
```